# LDA in Python, I get characters not topics

Tags: python, nltk, lda, topic-modeling

I am a little confused to perform LDA in Python. 
I have a document file, which I want to run LDA and get topics.

```
import docx
import nltk
import gensim
from gensim.models import hdpmodel, ldamodel
from gensim import corpora
def getText(filename):
    doc = docx.Document(filename)
    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        fullText.append(para.text)
    return '\n'.join(fullText)
fullText=getText('ElizabethII.docx')

#create lda object
stoplist = set('for a of the and to in'.split())
texts = [[word for word in document.lower().split() if word not in stoplist]
         for document in fullText]

all_tokens = sum(texts, [])
tokens_once = set(word for word in set(all_tokens) if all_tokens.count(word) 
== 1)
texts = [[word for word in text if word not in tokens_once]
         for text in texts]

dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]

lda = ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=5, passes=15)
topics = lda.show_topics(num_words=4)
for topic in topics:
    print(topic)
corpus_lda = lda[corpus]

print(lda.show_topics())
```

and as a result I get this:

```
(0, '0.723*"r" + 0.211*"f" + 0.025*"5" + 0.013*"-"')
(1, '0.410*"e" + 0.258*"t" + 0.206*"h" + 0.068*"m"')
(2, '0.319*"n" + 0.162*"l" + 0.113*"c" + 0.101*"u"')
(3, '0.503*"i" + 0.324*"d" + 0.113*"b" + 0.041*"9"')
(4, '0.355*"o" + 0.307*"s" + 0.106*"w" + 0.052*"v"')
```

which makes me confused. Why I get characters instead of topics? Is it because of my docx file( which contains 1900 words?) or mistake in code? or maybe I should provide topics for sentences(paragraphs)? (how?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use word_tokenize as shown below to prepare tokens consisting of words:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk import word_tokenize 
from gensim.models import ldamodel
from gensim import corpora

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
Doc1 = 'Data science is an interdisciplinary field that uses scientific methods, processes, algorithms and systems to extract knowledge and insights from data in various forms, both structured and unstructured,[1][2] similar to data mining. '
Doc2 = 'Biology is the natural science that studies life and living organisms, including their physical structure, chemical processes, molecular interactions, physiological mechanisms, development and evolution.'
docs = [Doc1, Doc2]

tokens = [word_tokenize(doc.lower()) for doc in docs]
tokens = [[t for t in token_list if t not in stop_words] for token_list in tokens]
word_l = WordNetLemmatizer()
tokens = [[word_l.lemmatize(t) for t in token_list if t.isalpha()] for token_list in tokens]

dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(tokens)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(t) for t in tokens]

lda = ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=5, passes=15)
topics = lda.show_topics(num_words=4)
for topic in topics:
    print(topic)

(0, '0.029*"science" + 0.029*"process" + 0.029*"living" + 0.029*"organism"')
(1, '0.114*"data" + 0.043*"scientific" + 0.043*"similar" + 0.043*"mining"')
(2, '0.029*"science" + 0.029*"process" + 0.029*"living" + 0.029*"biology"')
(3, '0.029*"process" + 0.029*"science" + 0.029*"living" + 0.029*"biology"')
(4, '0.048*"process" + 0.048*"science" + 0.048*"evolution" + 0.048*"physical"')
```

Comment: Thanks. But here docs are already distinguish sentences not a full text (like Wiki Page). So I shall breakdown the text into sentences before tokenizing?

Comment: Not really. The same code can work on a single document as well. Let me know if this is the case and I shall include another example

Comment: I run  the code, but also I find some punctuation in results. How I may remove them as stop words.
 I get something like: "=="

Comment: I have tested the code in my answer on a doc with the following = == - # } { [ } ] ; " & ! symbols. None of them appear in the tokens variable after processing the docs. You really ought to limit your questions to the immediate scope of the question you have posted on SO. If you still have problems with punctuation please post a new question outlining them in detail.